# Getting an error wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on SharedFolder

Tags: shared-folders

have installed Ubuntu 17.04 as guest OS in Virtual box and my base OS is widnows 10 . I am relatively new to Ubuntu OS

When I am trying to share the files between Host OS to guest OS I did the following things:

I set the Shared folders and the given name as "SharedFolder"
After that I have given the command    `sudo mount -t vboxsf SharedFolder /media/SharedFolder`

then this is the result now:
`$ wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on SharedFolder,
missing codepage or helper program, or other error
In some cases useful info is found in  syslog - try dmesg |tail or so.`

any help will be appreciated ;)

Comment: also i can't see sf_sharedfolder when im trying ubuntu file explorer.

Comment: If you installed Guest Additions, you should follow [official VirtualBox documentation on shared folders mounting](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#sf_mount_manual).

Comment: It is best if you just use the drop-down box in the guest additions to control the mounting of the folder.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried it with ntfs-3g  installed?

```
sudo apt-get install ntfs-3g
```

Comment: ntfs-3g is built-in in Ubuntu desktop and server.